# Store unknown key in l3keys

Tags: expansion, expl3, l3keys

Is there a good way to store the *key* of an `unknown` key-val in expl3? I can get `\l_keys_key_tl`, but it gets overwritten before it's expanded. I suppose I need to expand it when I store it, but I'm having trouble making that work, especially because I don't want to expand the value yet. Also, I expect to get multiple unknowns, and the order is important, so l3prop isn't appropriate.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_mymod_seq
\keys_define:nn { mymod } {
  a       .tl_set:N = \tmpa, % some keys are treated special
  % others are grouped with unknowns
  b       .code:n = \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymod_seq {(B~is~\f{#1})},
  unknown .code:n = \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymod_seq {(unknown~{\l_keys_key_tl}~is~\f{#1})},
}

\newcommand\setkeys[1]{\keys_set:nn { mymod } { #1 }}
\newcommand\printkeys{\seq_use:Nn \l_mymod_seq {,~}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setkeys{a=5,b=6,c=7,d=8}
\newcommand\f[1]{\textbf{#1}}
A is \f{\tmpa}
\renewcommand\f[1]{\textit{#1}}
\printkeys
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output showing the \l_keys_key_tl variable printing the same thing twice]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid code duplication by using self-defined functions and variants thereof. Here `\mymod_store:Vn` is just the same as `\mymod_store:nn` but the first argument should be a token list variable (other data types could apply as well) whose *value* is passed to the main macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_mymod_keyvalue_seq
\keys_define:nn { mymod }
 {
  % some keys are special
  a       .tl_set:N = \valueofa,
  % others are grouped with unknowns
  b       .code:n = \mymod_store:nn {B} {#1},
  unknown .code:n = \mymod_store:Vn \l_keys_key_tl {#1},
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymod_store:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymod_keyvalue_seq {(#1~is~\f{#2})}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mymod_store:nn { V }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setkeys}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { mymod } { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\printkeys{}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mymod_keyvalue_seq {,~}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\f[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setkeys{a=5,b=6,c=7,d=8}

A is \f{\valueofa}

\renewcommand\f[1]{\textit{#1}}

\printkeys

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (or anyone), can you say why you made `\printkeys` expandable? For that matter, why the protected `\mymod_store:nn`? As I understand, expandable commands have constraints that allow them to be used in `\edef`s, and protected commands don't expand in `\edef`s, but why did you use them here? The xparse docs have many warnings about using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` so I have thus far avoided them, so why are they necessary here?

Comment: @goodmami You might want to use `\printkeys` in an expansion context. Since `\seq_use:Nn` is fully expandable, there's no problem in doing it so. Of course, in this case, `\textit` is likely to break, but the issue is solvable in a different way.

Answer (score 8):

You can use expansion (`Nx`) to expand the key and then prevent expansion (`\exp_not`) for the unknown control sequence.

As @egreg mentioned in the comments you might want `\exp_not:n { \f{#1} }` instead of `\exp_not:N`, because this does not expand `#1` (the curenntly used one does).

[image: expand]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_mymod_seq
\keys_define:nn { mymod } {
  a       .tl_set:N = \tmpa, % some keys are treated special
  % others are grouped with unknowns
  b       .code:n = \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymod_seq {(B~is~\f{#1})},
  unknown .code:n = \seq_put_right:Nx \l_mymod_seq {(unknown~\l_keys_key_tl\ is~\exp_not:N \f{#1})},
}

\newcommand\setkeys[1]{\keys_set:nn { mymod } { #1 }}
\newcommand\printkeys{\seq_use:Nn \l_mymod_seq {,~}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setkeys{a=5,b=6,c=7,d=8}
\newcommand\f[1]{\textbf{#1}}
A is \f{\tmpa}
\renewcommand\f[1]{\textit{#1}}
\printkeys
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly `\exp_not:n { \f{#1} }` or the text in `#1` would be expanded in the `unknown` case, unlike the `b` case.

Comment: @egreg You're right, I supposed the `#1` should be expanded.

Comment: This was useful, and I think I'll use the `\exp_not:n` solution for a related problem, but I think @egreg's answer is more generally useful to the question as posed. One question for you: why does `\l_keys_key_tl\ is` insert a space before `is` but `\l_keys_key_tl~is` does not? I solved this with braces around the macro, but you must have changed it for a reason. Is there a difference between `\ ` and `~` in expl3 syntax mode?

Comment: @goodmami `~` is the LaTeX3 equivalent for an ordinary space. That means that it will look to TeX like a space after a control word and hence is eaten. For it to be visible I changed it to a forced space `\ `. And the grouping (braces) is something I dislike at that point (I do not like to introduce unnecessary groups).